# $\frac1{(a+1)^2}+ \frac1{(b+1)^2}\geq\frac 1{1+ab}$ for positive reals $a$ and $b$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}+ \displaystyle\frac{1}{(b+1)^2}\geq \displaystyle\frac{1}{1+ab}$ for positive reals $a$ and $b$

My idea was to apply Titu’s lemma but it didn’t work. Can you provide a proof that doesn’t simply use “brute force” a.k.a. SOS method? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the SOS method is, and therefore perhaps that this doesn't answer your question, but you could use the fact that$$\frac1{(a+1)^2}+\frac1{(b+1)^2}-\frac1{1+ab}=\frac{ab(a-b)^2+(1-ab)^2}{(a+1)^2(b+1)^2(1+ab)}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. By SOS method I mean the method you shown above (sum of squares)

Comment: I find that many inequality 'tricks' use the SOS property so you might be asking a bit too much.

Comment: Nevermind. I did it right now by using Cauchy Schawz: (a+1)^2<=(1+ab)(1+a/b) simply applying this gives the inequality.

Comment: Now you can add your proof to your question. This question can still accept answers if you ask for a proof without Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 3):

By C-S
$$\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(b+1)^2}=\frac{b^2}{b^2(a+1)^2}+\frac{a^2}{a^2(b+1)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(a+b)^2}{2a^2b^2+2ab(a+b)+a^2+b^2}=\frac{(a+b)^2}{(1+ab)(a+b)^2-ab((a-1)^2+(b-1)^2)}\geq\frac{1}{1+ab}.$$

Comment: I also did it with Cauchy Schwarz by introducing the vectors (1,sqrt(ab)), (1,sqrt(a/b)) and (1,sqrt(b/a)) but it looked quite different from what is here (I applied CS twice, inverted the terms to finally sum both expressions). However I can't see where and how CS is applied here. Could you explain me please?

Comment: @Jeanba I used the following C-S: Let $b_i>0$. Thus, $\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+...+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\geq\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+...+b_n}.$